# Listview need to show the data from the database

Tags: java, android, search, android-listview

I am creating dictionary and I need to display the data from the database in the ListView. Hope someone can help me. Here is the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainlist);
    ls.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: This is only half the code.  Where's the other half?  You need to try that yourself first and then ask questions here

Comment: First , you need to know how to bind data to your listview. If you know that, then i think the rest can be sorted out. As for database access, i advice you use a content provider and not directly accessing it like the answers below are suggesting

Comment: As a hint, for database access, you could use a CursorAdpater to bind the data passed as a cursor object holding the required data. Remeber to close the cursor when all data is read to save memory and avoid stale data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a custom ArrayAdapter and a method that returns all the values that you need from the database,  probably a subclass of the **SQLiteOpenHelper** class.  Read about them in detail and eventually you'll know the answer.